# How to remove insignificant zeros from a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following string values.

```
00000062178221  
00000000054210  
00004210555001
```

How can I cleanup the string and remove the zero paddings from the left? I'm using C# and .net 2.0.
Expected results from above:

```
62178221  
54210  
4210555001
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be pretty efficient

```
string str = "000001234";
str = str.TrimStart('0');
```

Answer (score 12):

```
string s = "0001234";
s = s.TrimStart('0');
```

You might want to add

```
if (s == "") s = "0";
```

to avoid converting `00000000` to an empty string.